# Non-transitive set with transitive power set and union set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set $x$ is *transitive* if $x\subseteq \mathcal Px$. I understand that $\mathcal Px$ and $\cup x$ must be transitive if $x$ is transitive.

I was wondering if it was possible for a set $x$ to be non-transitive while $\mathcal Px$ and $\cup x$ are transitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathcal P(x)$ is transitive, then $x$ itself must be transitive.

Namely, let $y\in x$. Then $\{y\}\in\mathcal P(x)$, and since $\mathcal P(x)$ is transitive, $\{y\}\subseteq \mathcal P(x)$. This means that $y\in \mathcal P(x)$, and since $y$ was abitrary, we have shown $x$ to be transitive.

---

However, it is possible for $\bigcup x$ to be transitive without $x$ being transitive -- for example we could take $x=\{\{y\}\mid y\in X\}$ where $X$ is a known transitive set such as $\omega$.